# Angular 7 Url changes but nothing else happens

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular7

This is the first time I post here, I'm quite desperate. 
Im using Angular 7. The problem is that when I manually type the desired url, it works well, but when I press a button and use RouterLink, the url changes but nothing else happens. If I press F5, the page will reload and will go to that new URL that has changed without trouble, so it's not a url routing problem.

I only implemented the routerLink in two buttons for the moment (in cities-nav), while I test it.
I also implemented a temporary one in app-component.html just in case it was a Material menu problem, but it doesn't work either.
Console says nothing. And I have a console.log inside the onInit of the cities-nav component, which triggers the first time that loads the web, but not when I use routerLink, so it doesn't even get there.
I also tried executing a method with a (click) event. Doesn't work either.

My code is the following:

My app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<nav>
<a routerLink="/">Go home</a>
</nav>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { CitiesNavComponent } from './cities-nav/cities-nav.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "cities/Madrid", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "cities/:name", component: CitiesNavComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is my cities-nav.component.html

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span *ngIf="cityName" class="mdl-layout-title">{{this.cityName}}</span>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Cities</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/cities/Madrid" routerLinkActive="active">Madrid</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/cities/Barcelona">Barcelona</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" (click)="goToCadiz()">Valencia</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Cádiz</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link black-text" href="">ABOUT</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content"><app-content *ngIf="cityName" [cityName]="this.cityName"></app-content></div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my cities-nav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-cities-nav",
  templateUrl: "./cities-nav.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./cities-nav.component.scss"]
})
export class CitiesNavComponent implements OnInit {
  cityName: string;

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Cities nav component OnInit executed");
    this.cityName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("name");
  }
  goToCadiz() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/cities/Cadiz');
    });
  }
}
```

[First screenshot of tracing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLkW.png)
[Second screenshot of tracing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZgpT.png)

Comment: First you could try no log all routing events to check, if a routing event is triggered. You could do this by making just a small change in your routing module: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I enabled the tracing and watched the console, but I dont really know how tracing works yet, so I couldn't get anything from there. I took a couple of screenshots though, they are at the end of the post, maybe you can understand it.

Comment: I guess you captured this while already being on 'cities/Barcelona'. If so, it doesn't look like a navigation is started at all. At the moment I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I think I was in Madrid before starting the navigation. I repeated the process though, and the console threw the exact same results. I can give you more details or show you other results if you need

Comment: This should be easy enough to put up on stackblitz. Would help understand the issue you are facing. (but I bet the issue cannot be duplicated on SB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a long time I found out what was happening. I actually had two problems.

First one, I had to change this line in cities-nav.component:

```
this.cityName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("name");
```

To:

```
this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
  this.cityName = routeParams.name;
  })
```

Because I always was on the path 'cities/:name', so even if I changed from one city to another, it didn't get the name again from the input. So that subscribe solves the problem, and will give you the new param every time you change the variable inside the same path.

The other problem was inside the app-content, because inside onInit I called the cityService which got a city by a name. The problem was similar to the other one, it only reached the city once, even if the city input name changed. So the solution was creating a method ngOnChanges as follows:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
//Add '${implements OnChanges}' to the class.
this.getCityByName(this.cityName);
}
```

This way every time the component input 'cityName' changes, it will get the new city and update.

Answer (score 0):

console log in the ngOnInit will be called only once.If you want to detect change in the parameters then subscribe to the paraMap in activateRoute.

created a sample demo in the link below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mriyze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcities-nav.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just posted mine and read yours afterwards. It would have helped me a lot, so thanks :)